# SQLite no funciona

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

Estoy tratando de usar sqlite, pero no me funciona.

Apenas estoy haciendo la estructura este es el código de mi clase `conexión()`:

```
class conexion {
    String url = "C:\\Users\\Juan\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\JavaApplication4\\doc_sal.db";
    Connection connect;

    public void connect() {
        try {
            connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + url);
            if (connect != null) {
                System.out.println("Conectado");
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.err.println("No se ha podido conectar a la base de datos\n" + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void close() {
        try {
            connect.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(conexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

Aquí está mi clase principal:

```
public class JavaApplication4 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        conexion cn=new conexion();
        cn.connect();
    }
    
}
```

Pero siempre me manda este mensaje

> No se ha podido conectar a la base de datos
>
> No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlite:C:\Users\Juan\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication4\doc_sal.db

Quisiera saber el por que no entra en la base de datos.

Comment: ¿Has incluido correctamente la ruta al jar? ¿Qué versión usas? Si pones en tu código `Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");` y te salta una excepción `Unhandled exception type ClassNotFoundException` entonces es que no la tienes bien incluida.

Comment: ¿Como se incluye eso? te refieres a la ruta del jdk uso esta versión jdk1.8.0_111

Comment: No si me apareció el mensaje de conectado

Comment: Pues ya sabes, lo que te faltaba era eso :) Voy a redactar la respuesta.

Comment: muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: De nada, un placer ser de ayuda. Ya he redactado la respuesta y la acabo de actualizar con una explicación más detallada del problema :)

Comment: Funcionó lo de DriverManager. La linea de Class.forName no me funciono.
Ya hice un proyectito con un driver de mysql y la verdad es que esto de registrar la clase me desoriento un poco ya que para ese driver no inclui la linea de registro del driver. Gracias!
Saludos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para establecer la conexión con un origen de datos JDBC no sólo debes hacer uso de [`DriverManager.getConnection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html), también debes registrar la clase que se encargará de gestionar la conexión con [`Class.forName()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String)):

```
public void connect() {
    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + url);
        if (connect != null) {
            System.out.println("Conectado");
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.err.println("No se ha podido conectar a la base de datos\n" + ex.getMessage());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("El JAR no está correctamente agregado\n"
          + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Tal y como puede leerse en la documentación oficial de Java:

> A call to `forName("X")` causes the class named `X` to be initialized.

En castellano:

> Una llamada a `forName("X")` causa que la clase llamada `X` sea inicializada.

Durante el proceso de inicialización de la clase ésta se registra como driver JDBC.

---

De manera similar podríamos registrar la clase haciendo uso de [`DriverManager.registerDriver()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#deregisterDriver(java.sql.Driver)):

```
DriverManager.registerDriver(new org.sqlite.JDBC());
```